# splitting an image into mutiple images

Tags: android

I've searched the web for help and although it looked like a solution it turned out to not work so good. For starters I'd like to say I've just jumped into android programming (this is my first day) I really learn by trial and error I'd like it that if you could help me you'd give me hints rather than paste the code in front of me.

my tileset
http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4654/tileseth.png
the result
http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/7913/resultx.png

the issues I'm having is 1. it is obviously not splitting the image in 32 by 32 bits. is what I'm trying to achieve is take my big image and split it into 9* smaller images of 32 by 32 portions. Secondary the image quality gets distorted and I can't work out why.
*I don't want to use a 9 patch as there will be more then 9 images soon just a fluke that atm I have 9 images

my code (evidently plagiarized from the internet)

```
    tilesetSliced = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 96, 96, true);
    tileset[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 0, 0, 32, 32);
    tileset[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 32, 0, 32, 32);
    tileset[2] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 64, 0, 32, 32);
    tileset[3] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 0, 32, 32, 32);
    tileset[4] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 32, 32, 32, 32); 
    tileset[5] =  Bitmap.createBitmap(tilesetSliced, 64, 32, 32, 32);
```

I'll make it more efficent once I got it working >.< any help would be great

the on draw

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  //update();
   for(int x=0; x<= mapWidth; x++){
          for(int y = 0; y <= mapHeight; y++){
                   canvas.drawBitmap(tileset[map[x][y]], x *32, y*32, null);
           }
     }
}
```

o.k some more debugging has shead light on something 1. I removed the scaledbitmap that stopped the quality being destroyed (orginally ahd it due to bugs) however I found out that for some reason it thinks the width of my tileset is 64 when its 96 any help would be nice on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck with a [Bitmap Factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to generate your `tilesetSliced`.  Within it is an `Options` class that allows you to set the sample size (`inSampleSize`) which can be used to scale down your image.  It may not be precise enough for your needs, however.

Your images are likely distorted due to the scaling down process.  Are you able to create these images with the right dimensions or pre-scale them?

Comment: I doubt scaling down my image would work, even if I scaled down the image by X from point x.y (which could work) it would be so much trail and error I'd proberly rather shoot my self in the foot. As for the scailing down process there shouldn't be the bmp which tilesetSliced takes it from is also 96 by 96 pixels in size (its a bitmap factory) basically in my gameView class I create the factory tileSet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tileset) and then pass it off onto the map class which then slices the image up and generates the map randomly.

Comment: o.k some more debugging has shead light on something 1. I removed the scaledbitmap that stopped the quality being destroyed (orginally ahd it due to bugs) however I found out that for some reason it thinks the width of my tileset is 64 when its 96 any help would be nice on this.

Comment: o.k and now I've fixed it for some reason putting it in the drawable-hdppi made it so width could only be 64 pixels any one know why? edit or not >.< grass is displaying fine by water tile is still cut off /sigh